# Checking for brackets and removing them

Tags: c#

I have actually misunderstood the issue originally,

Basically I have checks to see if there is an error, and to check for certain horrible characters that will break it, however this will not work with brackets, i need to basically check if there are ANY brackets within the string before passing it through SQL and if there are, remove them outright from the string.

for example say I have a string that looks like

```
[I am a magical string with super powers!){
```

I wish to remove all of these horrible brackets!

```
 if (compiler.Parser.GetErrors().Count == 0)
        {
            AstNode root = compiler.Parse(phrase.ToLower());
            if (compiler.Parser.GetErrors().Count == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    fTextSearch = SearchGrammar.ConvertQuery(root, SearchGrammar.TermType.Inflectional);
                }
                catch
                {
                    fTextSearch = phrase;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fTextSearch = phrase;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fTextSearch = phrase;
        }

        string[] errorChars = errorChars = new string[]
        {
            "'",
            "&"
        };

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string[] splitString = fTextSearch.Split(errorChars, StringSplitOptions.None);

        int numNewCharactersAdded = 0;
        foreach (string itm in splitString)
        {
            sb.Append(itm); //append string
            if (fTextSearch.Length > (sb.Length - numNewCharactersAdded))
            {
                sb.Append(fTextSearch[sb.Length - numNewCharactersAdded]); //append splitting character
                sb.Append(fTextSearch[sb.Length - numNewCharactersAdded - 1]); //append it again
                numNewCharactersAdded++;
            }
        }

        string newString = sb.ToString();

        //Union with the full text search
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fTextSearch))
            {
                sql.AppendLine("UNION");
                sql.AppendLine(commonClause);
                sql.AppendLine(string.Format("AND CONTAINS(nt.text, '{0}', LANGUAGE 'English')", newString));
            }
```

Comment: Check out the [`System.String.IndexOf` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx).

Comment: is it the same two characters every time?

Comment: It will only apply to brackets I.E

Comment: similar to my answer on your other question then.  use string replace.

Comment: and the brackets will only appear at the beginning and end of the string?

Comment: Please check the updated problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one way to do it.  You can make it more sophisticated by having a set of characters passed in and then testing for those characters rather than hard coding for the brackets.

```
var someString = "[Hello"
if(someString.contains("["))
{
    someString.Replace("[","");
}
if (someString.Contains("]"))
{ 
    someString.Replace("]","");
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply again, I have actually realised that I misunderstood the initial issue and I have redone the question to reflect the current issue.

Comment: ok.  if I am understanding correctly you just want to remove every instance of opening or closing brackets.  if so this code will work.  But couldn't you just escape them with a "\" if it is for insert into a sql db?

Comment: It causes to many issues, I have tried this route but it simply does not work. I am still left with syntax errors!

Comment: sql is an odd beast for sure sometimes.  the above code should work for you.

Comment: http://paste.strictfp.com/30841?key=c263b5c686bac67ef150e4b2ead9b07a

This is how I am now doing it, it currently grumbling about the brackets[] having no value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you just want to remove the brackets if they are not matching.

This will accomplish that:

```
    public string MatchPair(string input, string item1, string item2)
    {
        var ix1 = input.IndexOf(item1);
        var ix2 = input.IndexOf(item2);

        if ((ix1 != -1) && (ix2 != -1))
        {
            return input;
        }

        if (ix1 == -1)
        {
            return this.CutString(input, ix2, item2);
        }

        if (ix2 == -1)
        {
            return this.CutString(input, ix1, item1);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    public string CutString(string input, int ix, string item)
    {
        string left = input.Substring(0, ix);
        string right = input.Substring(ix + item.Length);

        return left + right;
    }
```

Here is some testdata that I used:

```
        var str1 = "[hello]";
        var str2 = "[hello";
        var str3 = "hel]lo";
        var str4 = "hel[lo";

        var res1 = this.MatchPair(str1, "[", "]");
        var res2 = this.MatchPair(str2, "[", "]");
        var res3 = this.MatchPair(str3, "[", "]");
        var res4 = this.MatchPair(str4, "[", "]");
```